# How to write stored procedure using StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written following code using string builder.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select distinct tc.bracode as [Branch Code] ,tc.braname as [Branch Name], tc.collname as [College Name],tu.uniname as University from tblcollegelist tc inner join tbluniversity tu on tc.uniid=tu.uniid where ( ");

for (int i = 0; i < uni.Count; i++)
{
    query.Append("tu.uniname='" + uni[i] + "'");

    if (i < uni.Count - 1)
    {
        query.Append(" or ");
    }
}

query.Append(" ) ");
query.Append(" and ");
query.Append(" ( ");

for (int i = 0; i < branch.Count; i++)
{
    query.Append("tc.braname='" + branch[i] + "'");

    if (i < branch.Count - 1)
    {
       query.Append(" or ");
    }
}

query.Append(" ) ");
query.Append("group by tc.bracode ,tc.braname , tc.collname,tu.uniname");

string sqlquery = query.ToString();

cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

dt.Load(dr);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

can we pass multiple values to stored procedure using a parameter in C#?
ex:- select * from table where country in ('India' 'USA' 'UK')

here country has three values, how can I pass these three values to store procedure?

Comment: This is not a stored procedure. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of your problem is not that straight forward and the query which you shared needs to be optimized.
First thing is, instead of using `or` for comparing multiple values against a single column, you should use `IN` clause. Sample query with `IN` would look as following.

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table1 WHERE column2 IN ('val1','val2','val3')
```

This will return the result when `column2` matches any of the provided values in the list.

To achieve this via stored procedure you need to use feature called `Table-valued Parameter`.

For that first a type of table should be created in Database as following.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ValueList
AS TABLE
(
    strValue NVARCHAR(50)
);
```

Then the stored procedure should be have a parameter of this table type which so that you can use it to pass values from it ot `IN` clause.

Following is a simple Stored Proc which uses Table type as a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectToken
    @List AS dbo.ValueList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * From Token  WHERE UserId IN (SELECT strValue FROM  @List)
END
GO
```

Here `@List` is the parameter of type `ValueList` created earlier. Select query uses subquery to retrieve values from `@List` which are passed to the `IN`.

Following is the C# code which calls this stored proc by passing Table-Valued parameter.

```
public static List<string> GetTokensForUsers(List<string> userIds)
{

   //Prepare table structure to be passed to the command as parameter.
   DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
   var dc = new DataColumn("strValue", typeof(string));
   tvp.Columns.Add(dc);

   //Add values to the table which will be used in the stored proc.
   foreach (var userId in userIds)
   {
       var dr = tvp.NewRow();
       dr["strValue"] = userId;
       tvp.Rows.Add(dr);
   }

   var tokens = new List<string>();

   using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDb;user id=username;password=pwd"))
   {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectToken", conn);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       //Pass table as parametr to the command.
       SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@List", tvp);
       //Setting Type of the parameter.
       tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
       conn.Open();

       var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (reader.Read())
       {
           tokens.Add(reader.GetString(1));
       }

   }
   return tokens;
}
```

I have provided the solution with sample use case and code. It might not fit directly to your requirement but this can give you direction about how to resolve your issue.

Comment: thank you, i will try this method.